# Map get(key) return undefined

Tags: javascript

I map the id as key and whole object as value. I want to get object from map by key, but it returns undefined value. What's wrong ?

```
var arr = [ { id: '1', value:'value1'}, { id: '2', value:'value2'}, { id: '3', value:'value3'}];

//using lodash
var idsMap = new Map(_.chain(arr).indexBy('id').mapValues(this));

idsMap.get(1); // return undefined
idsMap.get('1') // return undefined


var idsMap2= new Map(arr.map((el) => [el.id, el]));
idsMap2.get(1); // return undefined
idsMap2.get('1') // return undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one works for me:

```
var arr = [ { id: '1', value:'value1'}, { id: '2', value:'value2'}, { id: '3', value:'value3'}];
var idsMap2 = new Map(arr.map(function(el) { return  [el.id, el] }));

console.log(idsMap2.get('2'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yxdug5j1/

The indices are of course of type string

Answer (score 0):

The approach you followed to create map object does not work in all browsers. try the below code.

```
var arr = [{ id: '1', value: 'value1' }, { id: '2', value: 'value2' }, { id: '3', value: 'value3'}];

        var idsMap = new Map();
        arr.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
            idsMap.set(item.id, item);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it in nodejs, on the server side.